# Volume slider using Core Audio

Tags: cocoa, core-audio

I would like to implement volume and gain sliders in my Mac app. I already use code that sets the volume/gain to a specific level and tried to use it [sample code](http://bit.ly/1zjeqwn) with my sliders, but the volume/gain never adjusts, even though I can see the values from the sliders being passed to the routines. So what's the best to achieve continuous volume/gain levels using Code Audio?
Thanks

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress      address;
    AudioDeviceID                   deviceID;
    OSStatus                        err;
    UInt32                          size;
    UInt32                          channels[ 2 ];
    Float32                         volume;

    SSAudioDevice * targetDevice = [self getTargetInputDevice];


    address.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
    address.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    deviceID = targetDevice.deviceID;


    if(!targetDevice.ioLevel){
            volume = 0.5;
    }
    else{
            volume = [targetDevice.ioLevel floatValue] / 100.0;
    }


    size = sizeof(deviceID);
    err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( kAudioObjectSystemObject, &address, 0, nil, &size, &deviceID );


    if ( ! err ) {
            address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelsForStereo;
            address.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput;
            address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementWildcard;
            size = sizeof(channels);
            err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( deviceID, &address, 0, nil, &size, &channels );
    }


    if ( ! err ) {
            Boolean hasProperty;

            address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar;
            address.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput;



            address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

            hasProperty = AudioObjectHasProperty( deviceID, &address );
            if(!hasProperty){

            }
            address.mElement = channels[ 0 ];

            hasProperty = AudioObjectHasProperty( deviceID, &address );
            if(!hasProperty){

            }
            address.mElement = channels[ 1 ];
            // returns true, channel 1 has a VolumeScalar property
            hasProperty = AudioObjectHasProperty( deviceID, &address );
            if(!hasProperty){

            }

    }


    if ( ! err ) {
            address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar;
            address.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput;

            size = sizeof(volume);


            address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

            err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData( deviceID, &address, 0, nil, size, &volume );

            if(err){
                    address.mElement = channels[ 0 ];

                    err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData( deviceID, &address, 0, nil, size, &volume );

                    address.mElement = channels[ 1 ];

                    err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData( deviceID, &address, 0, nil, size, &volume );
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using AUGraph and audio units?

Comment: No, I'm not. Do you know of any sample code that can help me out?

Comment: The question as written is too vague to truly answer. Will you add details on your audio setup, what API you're using, and what code you've tried?

Comment: I'm using Core Audio and the sample code mentioned in my initial post. I have a slider connected via IBAction to that code. It takes the float value from the slider and uses that to set the volume.

Comment: There was no device mentioned in that post that I could see.  Please post complete code here as it makes the question clearer and will help those in the future with the same problem.

Comment: I've edited my post with code I use to set the input level. I can use this to set the input level to a specific level, but if I try to call it continuously as the slider is moved, the input level never changes.

Comment: Which device are you targeting?  You initially set `deviceID` to `targetDevice.deviceID` but then it is overwritten by `AudioObjectGetPropertyData`.  Also, where does `targetDevice.ioLevel` come from? I don't see how the value of a slider would be used in this example.